# Coldfusion - create a secure login area for an online account based on username, password and user_id (CFParam URL.user_id)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to create a secure login area using Coldfusion where the username, password and user_id (perhaps using the CFParam URL.user_id) defines what information is displayed once logged in - kind of like an online account. So using their own login credentials, the user would login and have access to their information **ONLY** without the pages defaulting to the first user in the database or by accessing another user's information by simply changing the user_id in the browser bar (Perhaps by encrypting the URL variables). Here is what I have always used for a secure login in the past (which works), which also has 3 Failed Login Attempts and a Timeout Session:

```html
<cfquery name="rs_user" datasource="source">
SELECT user_id
FROM table
WHERE user_id = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.user_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
</cfquery>

<cfif IsDefined("URL.MM_logout") AND URL.MM_logout EQ "1">
  <cflock scope="Session" type="Exclusive" timeout="30" throwontimeout="no">
    <cfset Session.MM_Username="">
    <cfset Session.MM_UserAuthorization="">
  </cflock>
  <cfset MM_logoutRedirectPage="index.cfm">
  <cfif MM_logoutRedirectPage EQ "">
    <cfset MM_logoutRedirectPage=CGI.SCRIPT_NAME>
  </cfif>
  <cfset MM_logoutQuery=ListDeleteAt(CGI.QUERY_STRING,ListContainsNoCase(CGI.QUERY_STRING,"MM_logout=","&"),"&")>
  <cfif MM_logoutQuery NEQ "">
    <cfif Find("?",MM_logoutRedirectPage) EQ 0>
      <cfset MM_logoutRedirectPage=MM_logoutRedirectPage & "?" & MM_logoutQuery>
      <cfelse>
      <cfset MM_logoutRedirectPage=MM_logoutRedirectPage & "&" & MM_logoutQuery>
    </cfif>
  </cfif>
  <cflocation url="#MM_logoutRedirectPage#" addtoken="no">
</cfif>
<cfset CurrentPage=GetFileFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())>

<cfif IsDefined("FORM.loginfield")>
  <cfset MM_redirectLoginSuccess="table/landing_page.cfm?user_id=#rs_user.user_id#">
  <cfset MM_redirectLoginFailed="#CurrentPage#?loginfailed=True&loginfield=#form.loginfield#">
  <cfset variables.blnAllowLogin=false>
  <cfset variables.isLocked=false>
  <!--- lets find the user --->
  <cfquery name="qryUserAttempts" datasource="source">
    SELECT
      user_id,
      dateLocked,
      failedLoginAttempt
    FROM 
      table
    WHERE
      username=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.loginfield#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="255">
  </cfquery>
  <cfif qryUserAttempts.recordcount>
    <cfif isDate(qryUserAttempts.dateLocked)>
      <cfset intMinSinceLocked=DateDiff("n",qryUserAttempts.dateLocked,now())>
      <!--- number of mins to lock (set to 5) --->
      <cfif intMinSinceLocked GT 5>
        <cfset variables.blnAllowLogin=true>
      <cfelse>
        <cfset variables.isLocked=true>
      </cfif>
    <cfelse>
      <cfset variables.blnAllowLogin=true>
    </cfif>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset variables.blnAllowLogin=true>
  </cfif>
  <cfif variables.blnAllowLogin>
    <cfquery  name="MM_rsUser" datasource="source">
      SELECT user_id, username, password
      FROM table
      WHERE username=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.loginfield#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="255">
      AND password=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.password#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="255">
    </cfquery>
    <cfif MM_rsUser.RecordCount>
      <cflock scope="Session" timeout="30" type="Exclusive">
        <cfset Session.MM_Username=FORM.loginfield>
        <cfset Session.MM_UserAuthorization=MM_rsUser.user_id[1]>
      </cflock>
      <cfset MM_redirectLoginSuccess="table/landing_page.cfm?user_id=#rs_user.user_id#">
      <cfquery name="qryUserAttemptsSuccessful" datasource="source">
        UPDATE table 
        SET
          failedLoginAttempt=0
          ,dateLocked=NULL
        WHERE
          user_id=<cfqueryparam value="#qryUserAttempts.user_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
      </cfquery>
      <cflocation url="#MM_redirectLoginSuccess#" addtoken="no">
      <!--- <cfelse>
        <cfif ArrayLen(Session.MM_rsUser.attempts) GTE 3><h2>You've exceeded your login attempts. Please try again later.</h2>
        <cfabort>
      <cfelse>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(Sessionm.MM_rsUser.attempts,Now())>
      </cfif> --->
    <cfelse>
      <cfset variables.failedLoginAttempt="">
      <cfif qryUserAttempts.recordcount>
        <cfif isNumeric(qryUserAttempts.failedLoginAttempt)>
          <cfset variables.failedLoginAttempt=qryUserAttempts.failedLoginAttempt+1>
        <cfelse>
          <cfset variables.failedLoginAttempt=1>
        </cfif>
        <cfquery name="qryUserAttempts" datasource="source">
          UPDATE table SET
            failedLoginAttempt=<cfqueryparam value="#variables.failedLoginAttempt#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            <cfif variables.failedLoginAttempt GTE 3>
            ,dateLocked=<cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
            </cfif>
          WHERE
            user_id=<cfqueryparam value="#qryUserAttempts.user_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        </cfquery> 
      </cfif>
      <cflocation url="#MM_redirectLoginFailed#&failedLoginAttempt=#variables.failedLoginAttempt#" addtoken="no">
    </cfif>
  <cfelse>
    <cflocation url="#MM_redirectLoginFailed#&accountlocked=true" addtoken="no">
  </cfif>
  <!--- End code for handling failed login attempts 
      <cfif IsDefined("URL.accessdenied") AND true>
        <cfset MM_redirectLoginSuccess=URL.accessdenied>
      </cfif>
      <cflocation url="#MM_redirectLoginSuccess#" addtoken="no">

  </cfif>
  <cflocation url="#MM_redirectLoginFailed#" addtoken="no">
  <cfelse> --->
</cfif>
<cfset MM_LoginAction=CGI.SCRIPT_NAME>
<cfif CGI.QUERY_STRING NEQ "">
  <cfset MM_LoginAction=MM_LoginAction & "?" & XMLFormat(CGI.QUERY_STRING)>
</cfif> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- Microdata markup added by Google Structured Data Markup Helper. -->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
    <title>login</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
      #target-content {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
        transition: opacity 200ms;
        z-index:3000;
      }

      #target-content:target {
        pointer-events: all;
        opacity: 1;
      }

      #target-content #target-inner {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right:48px;
        padding-top:30px;
        padding-bottom:48px;
        line-height: 1.8;
        width: 45%;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background: white;
        color: #34495E;
      }

      #target-content #target-inner h2 { margin-top: 0; }

      #target-content #target-inner code { font-weight: bold; }

      #target-content a.close {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
        transition: opacity 200ms;
      }

      #target-content a.close:hover { opacity: 0.7; }


      input[type=submit] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
      }

      .button_login {
          font: 16px/22px "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
          display: inline-block;
        color: #FFF;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:12px 20px 12px 23px;
        font-weight:500;
        text-decoration:none;
        border:none;
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
        background-color: #77bc1f;
        
      }
      .button_login:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
        background-color: #7d868c;
        color:#fff;
        
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 style="text-align:left;">LOGIN</h2>
    <cfif IsDefined("URL.loginfailed")>
      <h5 style="text-align:left;">Authentication failed. <br />Please try again.</h5>
    </cfif>
      
    <cfif StructKeyExists(URL,"accountlocked")><h5 style="text-align:left;">You've exceeded your login attempts.<br />Please try again later.</h5></cfif>
      <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST" action="<cfoutput>#MM_loginAction#</cfoutput>">
        <h5 style="margin-top:20px; color:#686868; margin-bottom:5px;" >Username: </h5>

        <input name="loginfield" type="text" id="loginfield"  style="font-size:18px; font-weight: 300; width:100%; height:30%;  border:none; padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px; padding-top:5px;  padding-bottom:5px;  position:relative; z-index:1;   font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; background: #f5f6f6; color:#7d868c; text-align:left; border-radius:0; -webkit-appearance: none;" />
        <h5 style="margin-top:20px; color:#686868; margin-bottom:5px;" >Password:</h5>

        <input name="password" type="text" id="password"   style="font-size:18px; font-weight: 300; width:100%; height:30%; border:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:5px;  padding-bottom:5px; position:relative; z-index:1;  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; background: #f5f6f6; color:#7d868c; text-align:left; margin:0; -webkit-appearance: none; border-radius:0;"/></h4>

        <input name="login" type="submit" id="login" value="LOGIN" />
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the posted code has worked in the past, what's the current problem?

Comment: @DanBracuk  As mentioned, what I'm trying to achieve is similar to logging into an online account (Ie. bank account). Where each user has access their private information **ONLY**. Right now all the pages on the secure side are dynamic. After login, however, it defaults to the first user_id, or first row in the table. At login, I need to link information from the database, based on the user_id, username, and password - something like a CFQuery WHERE user_id=cfqueryparam value ="URL.user_id", plus keep all the security functions I have above.

Comment: It sounds like you need to save a session variable and use that.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion is this?

Comment: The first command is a query without a where clause.  That could be the source of your problem.

Comment: One more comment: `...AND password=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.password#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="255">` indicates that you may be storing a password in clear text. If so, this is a very, very bad thing. Only one person should ever be able to know what the clear-text password is - the user. If it can be seen or recovered by anyone else, this is incredibly insecure.

Comment: And if you are limiting the entry to 255 characters, you probably don't need to be using a `clob` to store it.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Looks like Dreamweaver code. IDE wizards are notorious for generating a LOT of extraneous/dubious code, so may want to review it to trim things down and fix the issues mentioned above.

Comment: Also, be careful of confusing URL and FORM variables. A form POST creates FORM variables, not URL.

Comment: @Ageax good tip! I am using a form at the bottom of the page where the user can enter their username and password and hit submit.

Comment: @user3067421 What version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: *"After login, however, it defaults to the first user_id"* - As others said, it's because the 1st query has no filter AND the redirection code uses that query to set pass the user id to the landing page. In other words, it does this: `table/landing_page.cfm?user_id=#UseTheVeryFirstUserIDInTheQueryResults#`. However, as @JamesAMohler pointed out, you should be using session variables - not passing the id in the URL (which can be tampered with). **Ultimately, don't rely on wizard generated code. It's usually bloated and not designed for security/best practices** ;-)

Comment: @Ageax I love what you are saying and it sounds like the right solution, unfortunately I don't know enough on how to incorporate a session variable. Is there a link you can refer me too, or an example you could provide? Any assistance you could provide would be much VERY, VERY much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3067421 - It's just like assigning any other value to a variable. Only difference is 1) You must enable the "session" scope in your Application.cfm/cfc file before you can use that score. Then 2) You use the scope name "session" when assigning a value, i.e. `<cfset session.user_id = 1234>`.  Are you currently using an Application.cfm/cfc?  For more about session variables, see https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-persistent-data-and-locking/configuring-and-using-session-variables.html

Comment: Oh wait a sec.. the code IS already using session variables ;-) Just search the code above for "session".

Comment: @Ageax Yes I have an Application.cfm file. Unfortunately I did not write the original code above which is why I am seeking help. I tried adding the following `<cfset Session.user_id = rs_user.user_id`> in my Applicaton.cfm as suggested but it must be wrong. It's not working. :-(

Comment: @user3067421 - Yeah, that's not the right query name. Remember I mentioned there are multiple queries? "rs_user" is the one you agreed wasn't necessary. Truthfully the Dreamweaver generated stuff contains a LOT of redundant code, making it hard to follow what it's REALLY doing, even for folks that know CF ;-) If it were me, I'd probably scrap it and start over with code I did understand. Anyway, you need to do some old fashioned debugging. Namely -  (temporarily) comment out all cflocations so you can output the various values to the screen, to figure out what values the code is using.

Answer (score 4):

You do not want to use a URL variable to store/ pass the userId around. You want to store that as a session variable.

Then, as Dan Bracuk noted, the first query does not have a 'where' clause to limit what user's information would be returned.

You would use the session scope variable where you stored the user_id in that 'where' clause and make sure you parameterize it using `<cfqueryparam>`

Comment: Actually the first query probably isn't even needed. Though agreed that's definitely part of the problem. Some of the redirection code uses the wrong query `?user_id=#rs_user.user_id#, i.e. rs_user instead instead of MM_rsuser

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your suggestions! Yes it was built using Dreamweaver. I tried using the first query with the "Where" statement but with no success, and yes agreed that query is not necessary, I forgot to remove before posting the code. Yikes, yes thank you for catching the "Clob" it should be "Varchar". I will try using the query MM_rsuser for the redirection. I don't know much about session variables. If I used a session variable, what would it look like and where would I place it? Thank you!

Comment: I tried the suggestion of using the MM_rsuser in the redirection and I get an 500 internal error code again. I also tried adding the WHERE = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.user_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"> in the MM_rsuser query and still get an 500 internal error code.

Comment: I also found that using the first query works until I add the `Where` statement, then I get a 500 internal error again.

Comment: @user3067421 A 500 error is pretty much a "Oops. Something broke." message. Look at your logs to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Hopefully the actual WHERE clause includes a column name too. If not, that'd definitely cause the query to break (-;

Comment: @user3067421 - Ignoring the missing column for a sec- why do you even need that first query? i.e. If it's a login form, what's the point of running a query for user info - before the current user has even submitted the form to tell you who they are?

Comment: @Ageax You are right, I don't need the extra Query at the top. I was trying to figure out how to make this work as I described in a previous comment. Looking for any assistance.

Comment: @user3067421 What version of CF is this? That can make a huge difference in some of the suggestions for solutions.

Comment: @Shawn I'm not really sure. I am using Dreamweaver CS6 for the code, but I also have Coldfusion2016 installed on my computer. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: So this is running on ColdFusion2016? Is this a learning exercise? Regardless, if you're going to be editing code, you'll do yourself a huge favor by ditching Dreamwweaver and switching to Visual Studio Code or SublimeText or something like that. Both are free. And the code that Dreamweaver writes is sometimes "special".